# SympyをJupyterNotebookで使っていますがエラーがでて困ってます。

Tags: python

解決方法を教えていただければ嬉しいです。
このようなエラーが出ました「TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable」

動かしたいプログラムは以下です。

「# パラメータ(実数)」の項目まではエラーなしですが「# 各座標の計算」でこのエラーがでています。

```py
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import *

init_printing()

# 単位ベクトルとか角度の定義
angles = symbols("phi_0 phi_1 phi_2")# 原点から肩部への方向を表す角度
thetas = symbols("theta_0 theta_1 theta_2")# モーターの角度(±90deg)
unit_vectors = [Matrix([cos(angles[i]),sin(angles[i]),0]) for i in range(3)]
ez = Matrix([0,0,1])

# パラメータ(実数)
params = [(A,130.0),(B,200.0),(C,400.0),(D,130.0)]
params.append((angles[0],2.0*np.pi/3.0*0))
params.append((angles[1],2.0*np.pi/3.0*1))
params.append((angles[2],2.0*np.pi/3.0*2))
params.append((x,0))
params.append((y,0))
params.append((z,400))

# 各座標の計算
A_vectors = map(lambda x: A*x,unit_vectors)
B_vectors = [A_vectors[i] + B*(unit_vectors[i] * cos(thetas[i])-ez*sin(thetas[i]) ) for i in range(3)]
D_vector = Matrix([x,y,z])
C_vectors = [D_vector + D * unit_vectors[i] for i in range(3)]
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

[map](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#map) には

> function を、結果を返しながら iterable の全ての要素に適用するイテレータを返します。

とあります。
イテレーターに対して `A_vectors[i]` はエラー。

`B_vectors`, `C_vectors` と同様に, 以下のようにするとよいでしょう

```py
A_vectors = [A*x for x in unit_vectors]
```

Comment: ありがとうございます
A_vectors = [A*x for x in unit_vectors] これに変えると解決しました

Comment: ヘルプセンターには, [質問にあたって](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) やその中の [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) などあるので参考にどうぞ